# How to I convert the pointer output of this C wrapper for OpenCV's MatExpr, back into a MatExpr

Tags: c++, c, opencv

Here is my C wrapper  for OpenCV's MatExpr "/" operator

```
MatExpr* cv_Mat_div_S(Mat* m1, int m2) {
        return new MatExpr(*m1 / m2);
    }
```

I think I got this part right where I convert frame to a pointer to use in cv_Mat_div_S
and use a reference to it in the cv_Mat_div_S function

```
 Mat mat(frame);
 cv_Mat_div_S(&mat, 255);
```

But in trying to use the output of Cv_Mat_div_S  in a normal C++ cvtColor like below, I get a long string of errors, with this one being the most relevant:

error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘cv::Mat’)
      cvtColor(*mat, *mat, CV_BGR2Luv);

This is how I'm attempting to convert back into a MatExpr:

```
 cvtColor(*mat, *mat, CV_BGR2Luv);
```

I tried using an & in place of the * but no go.

I could use help converting the output of `cv_Mat_div_S` back to MatExpr to use in other C++ functions for testing...And If someone might notice the `cv_Mat_div_S` wrapper and verify if there is a better way to write it, maybe one that could accept more than one type for the value parameter...but not using a template  because I'm compiling it to a .so and its supposed to go in an extern C {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of cvtColor() is

```
void cvtColor( InputArray src, OutputArray dst, int code, int dstCn=0 );
```

MatExpr could be converted into _InputArray implicitly. But MatExpr could not be converted into _OutputArray implicityly. (see source code of _InputArray and _OutputArray for more)

I try a test code snippet:

```
Mat a0;
MatExpr a(a0);
cvtColor(*(&a), *(&a), COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
```

VS2012 has compiler error:

> ```
> error C2664: 'cv::cvtColor' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'cv::MatExpr' to 'cv::OutputArray '
> ```

So you need to specify a valid OutputArray (e.g. Mat instead of MatExpr) to save the converted Luv image.